# Why is this Google Plus link on a user profile is displayed as text and not as actual link?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614595/owen) on Stack Overflow has Google Plus link under their user profile's *Website* attribute. URL is displayed only as a text and not actual link to their Google Plus Profile. I pasted the same URL on a browser address bar and it seems to be a valid URL. When I viewed the page source, I found the URL is simply displayed within *`<td></td>`*

```
<td>plus.google.com/101232353560988836676</td>
```

I even tried pasting the above URL on my profile and it did display the link correctly. When I pasted the text `plus.google.com/101232353560988836676`, **`http://`** was automatically prefixed to make it a valid URL on my profile. This tells me it is not necessary to have *`http://`* before the URL text.

Why isn't this URL not recognized as a valid one for this user and displayed as such on the user profile?

#### Screenshot of the link appearance on the user's profile:

[image: User Profile Website link issue]

Comment: http:// missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an anti-spam thing, an undocumented part of the [new user restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user).

The url was converted to an actual link just after the user passed the 10 reputation points threshold (and went back to text when the user went under the threshold).